# Resample and reshape pandas dataframe using a trigger

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with multiple data channels and one trigger channel. The trigger channel is either 0 or 1. It is 1 when an event happens.

I would like to detect the onset of event (`trigger == 1`) and sample data channels in the dataframe so that I only get a specified amount of time after the event trigger.

To have a concrete example, consider this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

# time in seconds
t = np.arange(10)*0.1

# data channels and trigger
d = dict(y=np.random.randn(10),
         z=np.random.randn(10),
         trigger=[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=t)
```

so `df` is:

```
     trigger         y         z
0.0        0  1.764052  0.144044
0.1        1  0.400157  1.454274
0.2        0  0.978738  0.761038
0.3        0  2.240893  0.121675
0.4        0  1.867558  0.443863
0.5        1 -0.977278  0.333674
0.6        0  0.950088  1.494079
0.7        0 -0.151357 -0.205158
0.8        0 -0.103219  0.313068
0.9        0  0.410599 -0.854096
```

Assume I have a time window of 0.2 seconds. Then, when trigger is 1 at time 0.1 seconds and time 0.5 seconds, I want to extract y and z for a time window of 0.2 after this trigger and put them in a `numpy` 3D array with dimensions (# of events, samples in time window, # of channels).

In this example, the dimensions will be (2, 3, 2) for two trigger events, 3 samples within the 0.2 seconds time window, and 2 channels (y, z).

Is there an efficient way to do this in `pandas`? The only way I can think of now is to loop over the `trigger == 1` events.

Comment: Are the timestamps always evenly spaced as in your example?

Comment: Yes, this can be assumed true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the row indices where trigger is set:

```
idx = np.where(df.trigger)[0]
```

Expand that 1D array to a 2D one showing all the indices to be sampled (here we use 3 samples per trigger):

```
samples = np.arange(3) + idx[:,np.newaxis]
```

That's a 2x3 array:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```

Which we use to get the final result:

```
out = df[['y', 'z']].values[samples]
```

That's a 2x3x2 array of values from y and z for each trigger times the number of samples per trigger.

Comment: Wow, this is more than perfect! Thank you!